# Photoshop move all open documents as layers of single document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

Need shortcut or menu option to split document putting layers as separate documents?

I know for channels tab if you click on tab properties there's option "split channels" that does it for channels.

Also to combine back what's the shortcut?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are you perhaps looking for File > Export > Layers to Files?  The reverse would be File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack

Comment: Yes this functionality, except i want to work not with files, but with currently open documents (different currently open tabs), group them and split.